# Up arrow ripple overlapping toolbar title

Tags: android, toolbar, material-design

I'm building my custom toolbar for a project im working on.
Everything looks great except for an overlapping ripple from the action buttons onto the toolbar.

[Image for reference here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B51iOYT4Fio6OC05bkJkMU1FUVE/view?usp=sharing)

That happens on both sides of the toolbar( i.e with action buttons as well as navigation icon)

Here is the relevant code:

activity.xml

```
..<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/searchToolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    style="@style/ToolbarStyle">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>..
```

activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.searchToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.search);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/main_orange</item>

</style>


<style name="ToolbarStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?actionBarSize</item>
</style>
```

I have tried to remove the title from the toolbar and inserting a TextView instead, but the same issue pops up.

I'm seeing this issue on a Nexus 4 running API 21.
On an M8 running API 19 there is no problem, i understand that is due to lollipops animation engine responsible for the ripple effect.

Thanks fellas

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this do not set a background to the toolbar.
Wrap it in a LinearLayout and give that the background color.
Or just set the background in it's parent container if possible.